# Ctrl+Right click create in edit mode, not snapping to face when Xray mode is enabled

Tags: snapping, retopology

I'm trying to do some retopology and I use the Xray mode a lot for this.
The strange behavior is for example:
Have the High poly mesh ready.
Create an empty mesh object, and tab into edit mode.
Snapping ON, Face Project ON, Project individual Elements ON, Backface Culling ON.

When the mesh is in shaded mode, I can ctrl+right click to create vertices and edges on the High poly surface.

It snaps to the surface immediately as expected.

If I enable Xray mode because I need to see better, when I ctrl+right click, the new geometry is not snapping to the surface, it goes through it, some way into the volume.

If I still have Xray mode enabled, and I select this new geometry, and press G, Enter.  Then it snaps as expected.

Isn't this snapping, supposed to happen on creation, whether Xray mode is on or off?

I'm not sure if this is a bug or something that's just not working as I expected.

I haven't been using blender for retopology for a few months, but I seem to remember this working just fine, or am I imagining things?